# Why can't I move the file which has been created through 'head' command?

Tags: command-line

I used

```
head -n 20 file1 > toy
```

And then I tried to move this toy file to another place

```
mv toy ~/lab
```

It shows

```
mv: cannot remove ‘toy’: Text file busy
```

I waited 5 minutes and tried it again, still the same.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process is busy doing something with your file. Perhaps the file is corrupt or the file is in a state that is blocking the process.

Not sure what OS you are using, but `lsof` is available on linux and many unix platforms. `lsof` will show what process has a file open.

```
e.g. lsof filename
```

Once the process that has the file open is known, the solution is to kill the process. But check first that it is safe to do so. If you are unsure about that, reboot the machine instead of using kill.